# Segmenting/Differentiating reflective surfaces in images

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have some images where I wish to distinguish between the hood of the car, and the rest of the objects by any means necessary.

Specifically, Is there any way I can accurately *segment* the 'hood' of the car in all these images below? It contains some amount of light refections so using basic filters becomes tricky.

To be clear; I do not have any labelled data - but I think it is possible to achieve this with simple filters only.

A few samples:-

[image]

[image]
[image]

Is there any way I can somehow separate the hood of the car with the rest of the image?

1. Filters that convert the hood to, say black and the rest of the environments oddly identified as black or white **doesn't matter**. The only requirement is that demarcation between the hood and the surrounding road be present.
2. Any other way to accurately generalize and filter/segment/extract the hood based on other features are also welcome!

==> The real difficulty here is the reflective surfaces - I am well aware simple color based filters might have worked but the reflection causes havoc with the simple thresholding based methods I have tried! :)

Comment: Maybe consider segmenting by movement (non-movement of the hood) between frames?

Comment: @balmy: the reflections will move as well.

Comment: Yes but not the same direction. I don’t know how to do it but I don’t see any other way of figuring it out, other than using a static mask.

Comment: What about detect the road, remove it and other surroundings, instead of detecting the car hood directly?

Comment: you didn't say if you have video or not. on video data, this might be tractable. even if the reflections move, they move *differently* from the rest of the scene, and not just in a different direction, but differently differently, because the hood isn't a flat mirror, it's curved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this because the reflections that you see are legit image content, and the edge of the hood is not visible enough. Even the best semantic segmentation would fail.

I assume that the hood area is fixed wrt the camera, so the simplest is to draw the outline by hand.

Comment: There is still a colour and contrast difference between the hood and the road - wouldn't that the enough information for some basic set of filters to segment effectively?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Err, I agree, but I don’t know why your comment is directed at me. Looks pretty impossible to me on single images. But I imagine that some whizzy image analysis over successive frames won’t take long to figure out which areas of the image are bodywork.

Comment: @balmy: my bad, wrong addressee.

Comment: @neelg: I don't see any "color" and segmentation will segment all the features in the reflections rather than the hood. Basic filters will jus emit garbage.

Comment: @balmy: I also believe that from a single image this is impossible (especially using "filters"). You can indeed analyze a sequence and look for places that are "often" the same gray, but let me doubt that this will be effective.